# Toggle Div in other css Container

Tags: html, css

what goes wrong with my code? can anyone help me a bit?
want to show a div onclick other div.

```css
nav div#showdiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #999;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hiddendiv {
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #FFF;
}

nav div#showdiv:focus+section#hiddendiv {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="showdiv">Click me</div>
</nav>
<section id="hiddendiv">
  <div>Text</div>
</section>
```

I think I have some wrong selector code in the css. or is it not possible 
to toggle a div in other `container` / `div` / `section` etc.

Comment: you can do it with the help of jquery

Comment: [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) can't be used on a `div` element. Try `#showdiv:focus {color: red;}`, and it won't do a thing

Comment: @SarabjitSingh **jQuery** is not necessarily needed just for a button click, vanilla js is pretty much enough for that

Comment: Totally agree with @SarabjitSingh. No need to add a whole library when the same thing is easily achievable without

Answer (score 1):

You cannot with just CSS.

This selector
`nav div#showdiv:focus+section#hiddendiv`
will not work because `#hiddendiv` is not a sibling of `#showdiv`, so you cannot target it with a `+`.
Also, clicking will not `focus` the element (unless it is an interactive element, like a button, or a input)

You can accomplish what you want by adding some Javascript that, as an example, add/remove a class after the click event.

```js
document
  .getElementById('showdiv')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    const hidden = document.getElementById('hiddendiv')
    if (hidden.classList.contains('show')) {
      hidden.classList.remove('show');
    } else {
      hidden.classList.add('show');
    }
  })
```

```css
nav div#showdiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #999;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hiddendiv {
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #FFF;
}

#hiddendiv.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="showdiv">Click me</div>
</nav>
<section id="hiddendiv">
  <div>Text</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use :focus ond div elements. Focus can only be used on elements that accept keyboard events or other user inputs.

You may want to try using javascript (jQuery) to do that:

```
$('#showdiv').click(function(e) {
  $('#hiddendiv').show();
})
```

You can use `.toggle()` instead of `.show()` to switch between display: block; and display: none;

Comment: What you used is actually **jQuery** and not vanilla JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

You can use the jQuery toggle() method to toggle div on click.

```js
$("#showdiv").click(function(){
  $("#hiddendiv").toggle();
});
```

```css
nav div#showdiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #999;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hiddendiv {
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #FFF;
}

nav div#showdiv:focus+section#hiddendiv {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div id="showdiv">Click me</div>
</nav>
<section id="hiddendiv">
  <div>Text</div>
</section>
```